# How come sin_addr is a union if I have never declared it to be?

Tags: sockets

In socket programming, how come my compiler knows that sin_addr is a union if I have never declared it to be?

> server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

Also, while starting a socket:

> struct sockaddr_in server_address;

Is "sockaddr_in" a command that my compllier understand? is it a struct that can be changed?

Would be appreciated if you could explain it in a way that a newbie would understand. I am programming for less than a week.

Answer (score 0):

With a nice compiler, you can jump into the header files in which they are declared.

On my machine in `arpa/inet.h`(ymmv),

```
typedef unsigned int            __uint32_t;


#ifndef _IN_ADDR_T
#define _IN_ADDR_T
#include <machine/types.h> /* __uint32_t */
typedef __uint32_t      in_addr_t;      /* base type for internet address */
#endif /* _IN_ADDR_T */


/*
 * Internet address (a structure for historical reasons)
 */
struct in_addr {
    in_addr_t s_addr;
};

/*
 * Definitions of bits in internet address integers.
 * On subnets, the decomposition of addresses to host and net parts
 * is done according to subnet mask, not the masks here.
 */
#define INADDR_ANY              (u_int32_t)0x00000000


/*
 * Socket address, internet style.
 */
struct sockaddr_in {
    __uint8_t       sin_len;
    sa_family_t     sin_family;
    in_port_t       sin_port;
    struct  in_addr sin_addr;
    char            sin_zero[8];
};
```

Do you read from where it comes?

Comment: Oh, so when i #include a library at the beginning of my code I actually fill a lot of informations, that helps me understand things better now. Thank you

Comment: @Theprocodernotreallyxd if it helps you, **you can click tick icon at the left side and under the vote number.**